# Information not actually being stored inside array of nodes

Tags: c++, arrays, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

```
node* nodeArray[1000]; 
for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++){
nodeArray[j] = new node;
}
int nodeCounter = 0;
string temporary = "";
string cont; //file content
int i = 0;
while (getline(fileObject, cont)){
  for (int k = 0; k < cont.length(); k++) 
    cont[k] = tolower(cont[k]);
  while (i < cont.length()){
```

Here is where the problem comes in. The cout line tells me that my logic is fine in that it should be inserting nodes inside my array of linkedlists. But it's not actually adding them to the array of linkedlist.

```
    //cout << "nodeArray [" << nodeCounter << "] : " << temporary << "\n";
    insert(nodeArray[nodeCounter], temporary);
    temporary = "";
  i++;
}
i = 0;
nodeCounter++;

}
```

And here's my insert function that might be messing with the program

```
  void insertion(node* tail, string info){
      node* temp = new node;
      temp->data = info;
      temp->previous = tail;
      temp->next = NULL;
      tail = temp;
  }
```

Comment: Is the first two code snippets are from the main function? Please share clearer code.

Comment: Yes it's from the main function. However, the insert function is separate. It compliments a standard linked list node structure.

Comment: You change the local variable tail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a pointer by value, rather than reference, so the address the passed-in variable is pointing to is not changed.

Change
`void insertion(node* tail, string info){`
into
`void insertion(node*& tail, string info){` .

Comment: That fixed the problem of them being added to the array. Now I'm having the problem that instead of adding nodes to each individual linked list within the array, it overwrites it.

Comment: @ZacharyCollins tail is not tail but head.